# Consulta SQl en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Tengo que hacer una query y no termino de dar con la forma correcta.

tengo una tabla en una BBDD de oracle. En la que tiene los siguientes valores:

tabla ejemplo

```
numero |  clase   | modelo |
  0701 | especial | alto   |
  0702 | estándar | básico | 
  0701 | estándar | medio  |
  0705 | especial | alto   |
```

El usuario solo insertará clase y modelo pero quiero obtener aquellos registros que su número se repite tanto en clase y modelo. Pongo la query que llevo hasta el momento por si así se me entiende mejor.

```
Select * FROM ejemplo WHERE ((clase = 'especial' AND modelo = 'alto') OR (clase = 'estándar' AND modelo = 'medio'));
```

Esta query me devolverá 3 registros, 2 con numero 0701 y otro con número 0705 pero yo solo quiero que me devuelva los registros con número 0701 (coincide numero en los resultados obtenidos).

En esta segunda parte es donde tengo el problema y no termino de encontrar la solución por mas que busco.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se la intención que tienes, ni si te servirá para el resto de ocurrencias, pero para lo que está pidiendo exactamente la respuesta es realizar una agrupación y quedarte con las que se repiten 2 veces.

```
SELECT clase, modelo, numero, COUNT(numero) as Cuentas
FROM ejemplo 
WHERE ((clase = 'especial' AND modelo = 'alto') OR (clase = 'estándar' AND modelo = 'medio'))
GROUP BY clase, modelo, numero
HAVING COUNT(numero) = 2;
```

Comment: Los datos son inventados para lanzar la pregunta y que se me entienda. AL final lo que quiero es obtener el numero siempre y cuando coincida en el resultado de la query que he puesto o dicho de otra forma quiero obtener aquellos números que se repiten 2 veces en el resultado obtenido de la query. Es un poco lío pero los registros de la tabla están así, no los he creado yo.

Comment: He editado de nuevo la pregunta por si así se entiende mejor. Gracias!!

Comment: He cambiado la consulta, a ver si te sirve

Comment: Si, creo que le problema que me estaba encontrando era que estaba poniendo "SELECT * ..." y esto por lo que se ve no lo acepta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!